# Angular replace component selector with html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

Say you have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'passport-cell',
  templateUrl: './passport-cell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./passport-cell.component.scss']
})
export class PassportCell {
  @Input()
  public label: LabelTranlations;

  @Input()
  public language: PassportLanguage;

  @Input()
  public labelPosition: LabelPosition = LabelPosition.LEFT;

  @Input()
  public fontsize: number;

  public LabelPositions = LabelPosition;

  constructor() {}
}

export enum LabelPosition {
  LEFT = 'LEFT',
  RIGHT = 'RIGHT',
  CENTER = 'CENTER'
}
```

Now I really want to use the `<dd>` and `<dt>` tag however I can't make a `<dl>` list since no other tag is allowed directly after a `<dl>`

example:

```
<dl class="person-info">
<passport-cell class="surname" [labelPosition]="LabelPositions.LEFT" [label]="labels.surName"
    [language]="language">
    {{personInfo?.personName?.last | texttransform : TextTransform.UPPERCASE }}
</passport-cell>
</dl>
```

So it is possible to "remove" the custom tag and replace it with the actual HTML of the template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute or class selectors instead of tag.

```html
@Component({
  selector: '[passport-cell]', // for class selector '.passport-cell'
  templateUrl: './passport-cell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./passport-cell.component.scss']
})
```

And then you can use the component with the following attribute:

```
<dl class="person-info">
<dd passport-cell class="surname" [labelPosition]="LabelPositions.LEFT" [label]="labels.surName"
    [language]="language">
    {{personInfo?.personName?.last | texttransform : TextTransform.UPPERCASE }}
</dd>
</dl>
```

If you prefer class selector, then it will be:

```
<dd class="surname passport-cell" ...
```